# Problem with Python web scraper in PyCharm. (Beginner)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I recently started learning Python. In the process of learning about web scraping, I followed an example to scrape from Google News. After running my code, I get the message: "Process finished with exit code 0" with no results. If I change the url to "https://yahoo.com" I get results. Could anyone point out what, if anything I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
def __init__(self, site):
    self.site = site

def scrape(self):
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
    html = r.read()
    parser = "html.parser"
    sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
    for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
        url = tag.get("href")
        if url is None:
             continue
        if "html" in url:
            print("\n" + url)

news = "https://news.google.com/"
Scraper(news).scrape()
```

Comment: You have indentation errors, is the code the same in where you are running it?

Comment: the issue is with the line, "If 'html' in url:" this is checking to see if a string "html" is in any of the url's on the page. When I run through all the links on the page, none of them contain html. Are you trying to print all links on the page or just specific links?

Comment: @Alkadian I'm running this in PyCharm. I think the indentation got messed up when I transferred my code to here. In PyCharm, everything looks to be aligned how it should be.

Comment: @Kickin_Wing I am trying to print out all of the links on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:

    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
            url = tag.get("href")
            if url is None:
                continue
            else:
                print("\n" + url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    news = "https://news.google.com/"
    Scraper(news).scrape()
```

Initially you were checking each link to see if it contained 'html' in it. I am assuming the example you were following was checking to see if the links ended in '.html;

Beautiful soup works really well, but you need to check the source code on the website your scraping to get an idea for how the code is layed out. Devtools in chrome works really well for this, F12 to get their quick.

I removed:

```
if "html" in url:
            print("\n" + url)
```

and replaced it with:

```
else:
    print("\n" + url)
```